# "Die Anzahl der X und Y ..." vs. "Die Anzahlen der X und Y ..."

Tags: word-usage

Setzt man das Wort "Anzahl" in den Plural, wenn es sich auf zwei oder mehr Klassen an Dingen bezieht? Bsp.:

> Die Anzahl der Käufer und Nichtkäufer beider Gruppen ist exakt gleich groß.

vs.

> Die Anzahl**en** der Käufer und Nichtkäufer beider Gruppen sind exakt gleich groß.

Comment: Schade, dass [Wiktionary](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Anzahl) kein Beispiel dafür hat. Könnte man ja nachtragen, sobald wir uns hier einig sind.

Comment: Nicht vergessen: Im zweiten Satz muss es dann auch "...sind exakt gleich groß ." heißen.

Comment: Englisch ist hier wesentlich spitzfindiger und *fordert* den "possessiven Plural" - Deutsch betrachtet das etwas lässiger, erlaubt den Singular und der wird auch sehr viel häufiger verwendet - Im Prinzip wäre aber auch Plural erlaubt und "eigentlich der Logik nach richtiger"

Comment: Beide Sätze wirken eher hölzern. *Die Anzahl ... ist gleich* wäre völlig ausreichend, da man von Kardinalzahlen ausgehen kann, gibt es kein *knapp unterschiedlich". Was aber trotzdem offen bleibt: Es gibt Käufer A und Käufer B sowie Nichtkäufer aus den Gruppen A und B. Ist nur die Anzahl der Käufer bzw. Nichtkäufer jeweils identisch oder sind alle vier Gruppen gleich groß?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laut [Wiktionary](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Anzahl) gibt es Anzahl nur im Singular. Richtig müsste daher *die Anzahl der Käufer und Verkäufer* sein.

Der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Anzahl) sagt, *fachsprachlich* gebe es auch den Plural, verrät jedoch nicht, in welchem Fach. Mir ist der Plural noch nicht begegnet.

Answer (score 1):

Es kommt darauf an, ob du die Anzahl als ganzes (die Anzahl der Käufer und Nichtkäufer zusammen) oder ob du die Anzahlen allein (die Anzahl der Käufer und die Anzahl der Nichtkäufer) betrachtest.

Betrachtest du die Anzahl als eines, so ist das Signular von Anzahl korrekt.

Betrachtest du hingegen die Anzahlen getrennt, so ist das Plural von Anzahl (Anzahlen) korrekt.

Comment: In meinem Beispiel geht es um den 2. Fall. Hast Du Belege für deine These, dass der Plural korrekt ist?

Answer (score 0):

Im Deutschen gibt es einen wesentlichen Unterschied zum Englischen, auf den uns eine Lehrerin zu unserer Schulzeit aufmerksam gemacht hat:

Im Englischen:

> "The students take their book." bedeutet implizit: Es gibt insgesamt nur ein einziges Buch, das sich alle Schüler teilen.
>
> "The students take their book**s**." bedeutet implizit: Jeder Schüler hat ein eigenes Buch.

Im Deutschen:

> "Die Schüler nehmen ihr Buch." bedeutet implizit: Jeder Schüler hat jeweils ein Buch.
>
> "Die Schüler nehmen ihr**e** Büch**er**." bedeutet implizit: Jeder Schüler hat jeweils mehrere Bücher.

Da sowohl "X" als auch "Y" **jeweils** nur eine Anzahl haben, steht das Wort "Anzahl" logischerweise im Singular.

---

P.s.: Auch wenn im Wiktionary kein Plural erwähnt wird, habe ich gerade ein konstruiertes Beispiel im Kopf, bei dem das Wort tatsächlich im Plural - wahrscheinlich "Anzahlen" - stehen müsste:

Wir fordern zwei Leute auf, jeweils die Anzahl verschiedener Dinge aufzuschreiben.

Ich bin mir nicht sicher, aber wahrscheinlich würde man die beiden Leute dann bitten, ihre *Anzahlen* miteinander zu vergleichen.

Comment: Und wie sagt der Engländer, wenn jeder mehrere Bücher hat, wie der Deutsche, wenn es insgesamt nur eins gibt? - Man würde übrigens die Leute bitten ihre Werte miteinander zu vergleichen. :)

Comment: Das mit den "Werten" hatte ich bereits vermutet. "Anzahlen" klingt irgendwie komisch. Was die Bücher im Englischen angeht, ist es wohl wie mit dem einzelnen Buch im Deutschen: Hier kann man nicht unterscheiden, ob mit "ihr Buch" gemeint ist, dass jeder eines hat, oder dass alle zusammen sich eines teilen müssen.